# Performant AWS-Lambda logging

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

We need to have our AWS-Lambda logs sent to Fluentd and finally collected in Kibana. We need to make it in almost real time mode (10sec delay max). Currently we use TCP transport to send logs to Fluentd during the lambda execution. The main disadvantage of such approach is performance hit in the following places:

1. VPC initialization
2. TCP request(s)

The best solution in performance perspective, I can see so far, is to use "built-in" CloudWatch logging, which has almost no performance hit, and resent logs to Fluentd from it. The problem here is that to resend those logs you have to create another Lambda function which will handle logs pushed from CloudWatch. In a busy system like we're building it might cost too much as there will be a lot of logs.

Another solution I see is to have a lambda which starts by schedule (i.e. each 10sec) and pulls logs from CloudWatch.

I'm worried that we might be missing something and there's a better way or AWS suite tool to achieve the goal.

So the question is: from your experience is there a better way considering performance/cost ratio? What is it?

Comment: Question - why do you need real-time logging - are you parsing logs for events and reacting to those? Would another system not be a better idea if this is the case?

Comment: I think using a Lambda function to process CloudWatch logs would be the best. You can then tweak the memory-size of the Lambda to achieve your ideal performance/cost ratio.

Comment: @mcfinnigan, the 10sec log lag is our client's requirements. Afaic, there's no downstream system after Kibana and logs are intended to be viewed by a life person in case of issues.

Comment: How about putting SQS between lambda and fluentd?